# Fill gaps in new array based on different lengths arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I am trying to create one array out of the two. Two arrays may be different lengths therefore the combine result should accommodate that and fill gaps with `null`.

My understanding is to first find a bigger array and loop over that, fill the gaps in the smaller array, and once that is done, merge it.

This is what I have done so far, but it feels very clunky, to the point I am starting to think - there must be a better way - less loops and maybe use some of the php array helpers methods ?

```
<?php

$result_keys = [];

$result_data = [];

$bigger = null;

$smaller = null;

$array1 = [
        [
            'dog' => 2,
            'cat' => 3,
        ],
        [
            'dog' => 4,
            'cat' => 2,
        ],
        [
            'dog' => 2,
            'cat' => 3
        ]
    ];

$array2 = [
        [
            'bird' => 7,
        ],
        [
            'bird' => 5
        ]
    ];

// find which array is bigger
if (count($array1) >= count($array2)) {
  $bigger = $array1;
  $smaller = $array2;
} else {
  $bigger = $array2;
  $smaller = $array1;
};

// loop over bigger array
foreach ($bigger as $i => $record) {

    foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
        if ($i === 0) {
            $result_keys[] = $key;
        };
        $result_data[$i][] = $value;
    }

 // fill gaps in smaller array    
    if (!isset($smaller[$i])) {
        foreach ($smaller[$i-1] as $key => $value) {
            $smaller[$i][$key] = null;
        }
    }

};

// loop over smaller array
foreach ($smaller as $i => $record) {
    foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
        if ($i === 0) {
            $result_keys[] = $key;
        };
        $result_data[$i][] = $value;
    }  
};

var_dump($result_keys);
var_dump($result_data);


// // expected result
// $result_keys = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird'];

// $result_data = [
//     [2,3,7],
//     [4,2,5],
//     [2,3,null]
// ];
```

Comment: Please add an example of the desired output to your question

Comment: @Claudio the expected output is at the end of the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to your problem:

```
$array1 = [
    [
        'dog' => 2,
        'cat' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'dog' => 4,
        'cat' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'dog' => 2,
        'cat' => 3
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    [
        'bird' => 7,
    ],
    [
        'bird' => 5
    ]
];

// get the number of values of the biggest array
$count = $count = count($array1) >= count($array2) ? count($array1) : count($array2);

$values = [];
$keys   = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $a1       = $array1[$i] ?? [];
    $a2       = $array2[$i] ?? [];
    $keys     = array_unique(array_merge($keys, array_keys($a1), array_keys($a2)));
    $values[] = array_values(array_merge(array_fill_keys($keys, null), $a1, $a2));
}

print_r($keys);
print_r($values);
```

Results (test [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2704021c2dfc18fb17bbc837c2104bc73718db74)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => dog
    [1] => cat
    [2] => bird
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 
        )

)
```